# Text-Indent for a text box in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, text-indent

I'm trying to push my text out of the textbox by giving it an extreme text-indent, but apparently text-indent is ignored/interpreted differently in IE.

Here is a simulation (try it in Chrome and IE to see the difference):
http://jsfiddle.net/Cernx/1/

Is there any workaround for this? Or is there anotherway of pushing text out of the textbox?

Comment: How about grabbing the `textbox` with some scripting and then placing that where you want on the page?

Comment: @JasonGennaro: It's not about placing the textbox, text-indent is about where text starts inside the textbox.

Comment: Ok.  I gotcha.  So why do you want to remove the text?

Comment: In the project this is only sometimes applying to the textbox. (not always)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#paaa { text-indent:50px; display: block; line-height: 1; }
```

Add line-height to make it work in IE. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cernx/12/)