# css text-indent on input text doesn't work in internet explorer 10

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to customize a text input with css, i want the text inside it to have a margin of 10px to the left so i use:

```
#text{
text-indent: 10px;
border: 1px solid #333;
outline: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 168px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

It works in all browsers except for IE10 which seems to ignore the `text-indent` property, how can i fix it?

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

Comment: Also see following question for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797103/text-indent-for-a-text-box-in-ie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use padding-left, it works on all browsers:

```
#text {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 158px; //decrease width with the same padding vale so that the width would stay the same
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use a special rule for IE, adding `display: inline-block` and a `line-height`, along with the `text-indent` rule, will fix this as well.  This is an old trick for both IE7-9 as well.

```
input.special {
    text-indent: 150px;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

Does the trick.

This is good if you are using liquid or responsive widths and you don't want to have to adjust your input's width on account of the padding.

Comment: While this will fix the problem, it does not isolate (and only apply to) Internet Explorer - the styles will also apply to other browsers and it causes a full height cursor, which is generally ugly.

Comment: Works also with display:block.